# How can you find translations of a word in english to other languages programmatically

Tags: java, translation

The following is a sample set of translations from `english --> french`

```
lundi (monday)
mardi (tuesday)
mercredi (wednesday)
janvier (january)
```

Is there an easier way to find the equivalent words for days and months from english to say french | german | japanese?

Comment: Do you already have the data (i.e. the mappings) available to your application and are wondering how to program the lookup; or are you asking where you can *get* the data from?

Comment: I don't have the mapping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fr");
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", locale);
System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
```

Now instead of `new Date()` create a date with the required day - monday, tuesday, etc

Answer (score 4):

I would consider using java.text.SimpleDateFormat with a correct Locale - it should provide day/month names in many languages.